# How to register http module in IIS 10

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, ihttpmodule, iis-10

I want to register my custom http module in web.config file. When I register under system.webServer section

```
<system.webServer>
```

But it didn't run into http module in visual studio 2015.  The madn seems just introduce it how to register in iis6,iis7. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673(v=vs.110).aspx

How to register it above iis8? In visual studio 2015, the development IIS express version is IIS 10.

Answer (score 1):

As you can find from this MSDN page about [Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/modules/), the `<modules>` element was introduced in IIS 7 and was not modified since then (all the way from IIS 7 to IIS 10).

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <add name="HelloWorldModule" type="HelloWorldModule" />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```